# /map and /odom after mapping the environment

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot-gazebo, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

1.
I have managed to build a map using turtlebot simulator in gazebo and I see that the building of map is rather bad. I hope its because of the odometry instability in gazebo. Or am i missing something here. Any tricks to build a better map.

Note: I used the one that is available in turtlebot_navigation [here](http://ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM).

2
I see that the tf's of /map and /odom after building the map are quite separated. Does this confirm my assumption that the odometry is not stable for the turtlebot simulation.

3
In that case can anyone suggest me a good robot model that has stable odometry.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

Bad mapping: For example there are 4 tables in a room. When i move around the robot i see that after multiple scans of the same obstacle, the shape (occupied region) reduces to less than half and at times counts the actually occupied region to be free space.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12919//map-and-/odom-after-mapping-the-environment/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2012-02-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-02-07**:
Diaz: Added the issue to my question

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-02-07**:
What do you mean by bad? Is the map not self-consistent? Are angles/distances, etc inaccurate? Is the map just noisy? There are lots of factors that will affect the quality of a map, and problems with different factors can manifest themselves in different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't speak for the accuracy of the Turtlebot simulator, but I can say that I've used the [erratic_robot](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/Erratic) stack with a good deal of success.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-07**:
You can just copy snippets of the turtlebot's kinect.launch and add it to the erratic robot.

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2012-02-07**:
Ok... actually i need kinect to be there for my project. So can how do i add kinect to the erratic_robot. Do you think that can change the efficiency.

**Comment by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) on 2016-08-25**:
hi, dear @DimitriProsser, how to use the slam navigation? just run the two files: move_base_slam.launch and slam_gmapping.launch is ok?